# Django REST framework reset password confirmation not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am building a user authentication backend with `djano` using `rest_auth` and `allauth`. This is my `api` app's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),

    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    path("account/", include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

after running server, I am going to `rest-auth/password/reset`, type in the email and post.

an error occurs saying:

```
NoReverseMatch at /api/v1/rest-auth/password/reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I found this SO question which helped: [NoReverseMatch at /rest-auth/password/reset/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418233/noreversematch-at-rest-auth-password-reset)

and after looking at the django REST framework official demo: https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo.html,

I included other endpoints in my url.py as suggested:

```
urlpatterns = [

    # rest framework authentication: login/logout/signup etc ...
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),

    # url endpoint for registration
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

     # url endpoint to confirm email for change of password
     path('password-reset/confirm', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"), name="password-reset-confirm"),

     # url link to change password (sent via email)
     path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"),  name='password_reset_confirm'),

    # to handle different account emails (facebook, github, gmail, etc .. )
    path("account/", include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

where I also included my simple `html` landing page when resettinthe g password. This works. an email is sent with a confirmation link and the `html` pages load up. however after I confirm my email in my custom pages, the default page for the django REST auth password reset appears and I have to input the new password there again for the change in password to take effect.

Now at the moment, I would rather just use the Django rest template than my own. so is there a way to not call `template_name="password_reset_confirm.html"` and go directly to the django default?

or otherwise go directly to the django `rest-auth/password/reset/confirm` rather than my custom `'password-reset/confirm'`, which I only implemented to get rid of the error I mentioned.

what is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself. Daniel Roseman's is a good answer however if you want to use the Django rest framework's `rest-auth` for resetting the password with email confirmation, the below `urlpatterns` is the correct one:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_auth import views

urlpatterns = [    
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),

    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    path('rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm"),

    path("account/", include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

The missing knowledge in my case was the `views.PasswordResetConfirmView` which is the default view for resetting the password in `rest-auth`

Comment: `rest-auth` last commit was 18 Apr 2019, more than 1 year ago. It isn't very comforting to use such library...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have done this. There's no point assigning those URLs to TemplateViews, they won't have the right functionality to actually do the reset etc.

I think you are confusing URLs, templates and views. What you actually need to do is to create the relevant URLs, but point them at the existing Django views.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Comment: This works as expected. however, you are not using the django REST framework right? Why?

Comment: Doesn't [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) require a template that defaults to registration/password_reset_form.html? I ask this because OP wants to use in DRF to build a Web API.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the reverse urls to your urls.py.
Take this register function for example. There is a function redirect that will redirect you to the login page when successfully registered

```
@login_required
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'An Account has been created for the user  {username}.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?\